# tagging in Wordpress buddypress

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have this task to research or implement on buddypress. Is there a way to tag a post? (or similar to this function?)

It is like facebook, that you can tag him/her to your post/comment.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

> It is like facebook, that you can tag him/her to your post/comment.

If you are talking about a blog post I don't know if that can be done or not
But if you are talking about post as in buddypress (aka activity) yes you can.
..
install a simple plugin called

 BP Labs : 

This plugin allows members to "tag" also known as "mentions" (example: @jimmy bloom ) into a post, comment.